# Null Test: Caused an ERROR

Tags: java, xml, ant, junit

```
test:
    [junit] Running ProjProgAppsTest
    [junit] Testsuite: ProjProgAppsTest
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
    [junit]
    [junit] Null Test:  Caused an ERROR
    [junit] ProjProgAppsTest
    [junit] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ProjProgAppsTest
    [junit]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    [junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    [junit]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    [junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    [junit]     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    [junit]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    [junit]
    [junit]

BUILD FAILED
```

I got this output from my test. what causes the error? how to fix it ? can somebody help me?

Comment: If you want help on a build.xml file, then that's what you shoukd post. If you want help on why a build fails, then you should post the output of the build.

Comment: The <classpath> for <junit> must include junit.jar if nor in Ant's own path.

Comment: <target name="junit" depends="compile">
  <junit>
    <classpath>
      <pathelement location="bin" />    
      <pathelement location="lib/junit-4.12.jar"/>
    </classpath>    
    <batchtest>
       <fileset dir="${test.dir}">
            <include name="ProgAppsLabPrelimsClassesTest.java" />
       </fileset>
    </batchtest>
    <formatter type="brief" usefile="false"/>
  </junit>
</target>

Answer (score 0):

The JUnit Wiki has an article [Getting started – Ant](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Getting-started-%E2%80%93-Ant).

Comment: The <classpath> for <junit> must include junit.jar if not in Ant's own classpath. What must i do

Comment: <target name="test" depends="compile">
  <junit fork="no">
    <classpath refid="classpath.test"/>
    <classpath>
    <pathelement location="lib/junit-4.10.jar"/>
    </classpath>
    <formatter type="brief" usefile="false" />
    <batchtest>
      <fileset dir="${basedir}/" includes="Tests.class" />
    </batchtest>
        
        
  </junit>
</target>

Comment: You should use `fork="true"` and a matcher for the includes like `<fileset dir="${test.src.dir}" includes="**/*Test.java" />`.

Comment: Have you tried to follow the steps of the "Getting Started" article. It is a working example for you to start with.